# Idris: Hidden implementation and exposed equality

Tags: idris

Let's say I have a module.

```
module A
%default total
%access export

data D = A | B

Value1: D
Value1 = A

Value2: D
Value2 = A
```

Because the implementations of `Value1` and `Value2` are hidden, I would expect that it is not possible to construct a proof `prf: Value1 = Value2` inside of another module, but in fact it is possible:

```
module B
import A
%default total

prf: Value1 = Value2
prf = Refl
```

When I change the definition of `Value2` to

```
Value2: D
Value2 = Value1
```

I get the expected error.

Now I expose the equality of `D`s by extending module `A` with an implementation of `DecEq D`. It is now trivially possible to get an instance of `Value1 = Value2` at runtime inside of other modules:

```
main : IO ()
main = case decEq Value1 Value2 of
           Yes prf => putStrLn "Got instance of Value1 = Value2."
           No _ => putStrLn "This should not happen."
```

I would expect that using `decEq` it's also possible to get an instance of this proof at typecheck time. I have tried

```
prf: Value1 = Value2
prf with (decEq Value1 Value2)
    | Yes p = p
    | No _ impossible
```

and also this very hacky solution:

```
%language TypeProviders
prfProvider : IO (Provider (Value1 = Value2))
prfProvider = do case decEq Value1 Value2 of
                     Yes p => pure (Provide p)
                     No _ => pure (Error "This should not happen.")
%provide (prf: Value1 = Value2) with prfProvider
```

Both solutions do not work.

Now my question is: Why can I construct an instance of `Value1 = Value2` when `Value2` is defined by `Value2 = A`? And given an implementation of `DecEq D` is there a way to get an instance of `Value1 = Value2` at compile time and if not, why is it designed that way?